# What is the proper way to convert the generic type array and use it in java?

Tags: java

Food.java

```
public class Food {
}
```

Animal.java

```
public class Animal<E> {
    private E[] a = (E[]) new Object[5];


    public E[] returnArray() {
        return a;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal<Food> animal = new Animal<>();

        Object[] objs = animal.returnArray();
        Food[] fd = (Food[]) objs; // error happens here!
        fd[0] = new Food();


    }
}
```

error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ltestsample.Food; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Ltestsample.Food; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at testsample.Animal.main(Animal.java:19)
```

error happens when I try to convert the generic type array, Food[] fd = (Food[]) objs, it seems fd and obj are both Food[] array, what's going wrong here.

Comment: The correct way to deal with mixing arrays and generics is not to use arrays: use a `List<E>` instead.

Comment: But if the method return the E[] array, how to deal with it.

Comment: You can cast as appropriate, but this way is "dirty", and better to avoid it as per @AndyTurner's suggestion

Comment: You can give `Animal` a constructor accepting an `IntFunction<E[]>`, which allows a correctly-typed array to be constructed.